# What are the reasons why Slack API is getting failed_to_send_invite error?

Tags: slack-api

Currently using this code to send workspace invites via Slack API, this is working but for some emails it is getting this failed_to_send_invite error. At first I thought it was because of using test emails, but now we also encountered it with a gmail email. Any idea why this error occurs? Documentation only says "The invite failed to send." as the description for this error.

response = slack.admin_users_invite(team_id=workspace_id, email=invitee_email, channel_ids=channel_id, custom_message=custom_msg, guest_expiration_ts=guest_expiry_epoch,is_restricted="true")

Comment: It may be that the invite is being sent for second time (not first time) that it says that.

Comment: Where can I see that documentation(slack api page contains very limited details)? Email is newly created since we are still doing testing.